# Weird Page Views in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

Google Analytics, I noticed that there is some weird URL path under my domain that doesn't even exist;for example:

my domain is **ABC.com**

under page view I see: **ABC.com/products/L-apos.**

I have the path of "products", but there is no such thing called **"L-apos"** which is very weird.

When I did some checking I found that what mot people face is totally different URLs like porno links for instance; However, in my case, the domain is correct but the path doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

The html entity for a single quote is:

```
&apos;
```

Which is pretty close to your **L-apos**. Is it possible you have an errant `'` at the end of an href to the `/products/` page?

Comment: yes I do have many products that start with " L' " but in this case why Google Analytics doesn't display the whole URL, for example: ABC.com/products/L'oreal-Professionnel